# Cannot convert value of type 'listOfContacts' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

Here is Code

```
let logButton : UIButton = {
    let login = UIButton()


    login.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    login.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
    login.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    login.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 61/255, blue: 114/255, alpha: 1.0)

    login.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    return login
}()


@objc func loginButton(){
    let contactList = listOfContacts()
    present(contactList, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'listOfContacts' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Please provide a suggestion or solution for this

Comment: What you want to do ? show a viewcontroller /

Comment: @Prashant yes sir but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
 let contactList = listOfContacts()
 present(contactList, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You're trying to use contactList of type `listOfContacts` as argument to the `present` method that takes a type of `UIViewController` as a first argument which is the VC that is supposed to be presented

here is method signature

```
func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,animated flag: Bool,completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

Comment: im a little bit confused how to used this method can you elaborate please im just starting to learn swift code

Comment: my listOfContacts is a class from another swift file

Comment: im not using a storyboard on this project